# Simple Mandelbrot renderer runs out of memory

Tags: c#, graphics, fractals

Ive been trying to make an simple mandelbrot renderer just to get myself into c# and forms, but when i render the image the program runs out of memory sometimes.

The memory builds up to 2GB and then crashes.

But sometimes it builds up i a jigsaw pattern like this and dont crash:
http://puu.sh/l2ri9/2fcd47e6d7.png

==============Code to render================

```
Renderer.CreateGraphics().Clear(Color.White);

        double minR = System.Convert.ToDouble(MinR.Value);
        double maxR = System.Convert.ToDouble(MaxR.Value);
        double minI = System.Convert.ToDouble(MaxI.Value);
        double maxI = System.Convert.ToDouble(MinI.Value);
        int maxN = System.Convert.ToInt32(Iterations.Value);

        SolidBrush MandelColor = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

        for (int y = 0; y < Renderer.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Renderer.Width; x++)
            {

                double cr = fitInRRange(x, Renderer.Width, minR, maxR);
                double ci = fitInIRange(y, Renderer.Height, minI, maxI);

                int n = findMandelbrot(cr, ci, maxN);

                double t = ((n + 0.0) / (maxN + 0.0));

                MandelColor.Color = Color.FromArgb(System.Convert.ToInt32(9 * (1 - t) * t * t * t * 255), System.Convert.ToInt32(15 * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * t * t * 255), System.Convert.ToInt32(8.5 * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * t * 255));

                Renderer.CreateGraphics().FillRectangle(MandelColor, x, y, 1, 1);

            }
        }
```

===Link To Github page===
https://github.com/JimAlexBerger/MandelbrotProject

Comment: Are you compiling this as 32 or as 64 bit  ? If possible, you should compile this as 64 bit, it will give you access to more memory if you have it as 32 bit has a 4GB memory limit.

Comment: Do __not__ use `Renderer.CreateGraphics()` in a loop. Probably you should not use `CreateGraphics` __at all__. What is `Renderer`? A Control ? Best draw into a `Bitmap bmp`and use a `using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) { your loops here!}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not move `Renderer.CreateGraphics()` outside of the loop? The memory leak is probably caused by redundantly calling `Renderer.CreateGraphics()` without calling `IDisposable.Dispose()` on the `Graphics` object.

```
double minR = System.Convert.ToDouble(MinR.Value);
double maxR = System.Convert.ToDouble(MaxR.Value);
double minI = System.Convert.ToDouble(MaxI.Value);
double maxI = System.Convert.ToDouble(MinI.Value);
int maxN = System.Convert.ToInt32(Iterations.Value);

SolidBrush MandelColor = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

using(var graphics = Renderer.CreateGraphics())
{
  graphics.Clear(Color.White);

  for (int y = 0; y < Renderer.Height; y++)
  {
      for (int x = 0; x < Renderer.Width; x++)
      {

          double cr = fitInRRange(x, Renderer.Width, minR, maxR);
          double ci = fitInIRange(y, Renderer.Height, minI, maxI);

          int n = findMandelbrot(cr, ci, maxN);

          double t = ((n + 0.0) / (maxN + 0.0));

          MandelColor.Color = Color.FromArgb(System.Convert.ToInt32(9 * (1 - t) * t * t * t * 255), System.Convert.ToInt32(15 * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * t * t * 255), System.Convert.ToInt32(8.5 * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * t * 255));

          gfx.FillRectangle(MandelColor, x, y, 1, 1);

      }
  }
}
```